# Change block order of a binary diagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following binary matrix (numpy array):

```
M = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

In practice, it has two triangles on the diagonal.
I would like to reverse the blocks of the matrix, so that the two triangles appear on the other diagonal, but keeping the same shape:

```
M = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I have tried using a Dataframe with sort_index() and the possible combinations of axis and ascending but none of them worked.

How can I do that?

I need a general code, which works also for bigger matrices that have these triangular structures on the diagonal.

Visually, I would like to go from:
[image]
to:
[image]

Comment: IIUC, I think there is an error in the expected output on the last line (should be `[0, 1, 0, 0]`)

Comment: There was a mistake, but the other way round. I just fixed it.

Comment: Can you give the expected output if the array was: `array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]])
`

Comment: Given the explanation with the triangles, I really don't understand anymore what OP wants…

Comment: I added a visual image to try to clarify

Comment: no need for an image, just use the array I provided that has unique values: `M = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4,4)`

Comment: @mozway I don't think that is possible. I was able to do that in the image because I had labels on each point, maybe without labels I can't possibly do that operation. Sorry to have wasted your time

Comment: @Dario you can do it manually, just type the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject an additional dimension to reverse, temporarily. For this you have to know the size (or the number) of triangles along an axis:

```py
import numpy as np

# generate dummy input with 3 triangles of size 2
tri = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0]])
zero = np.zeros_like(tri)
arr = np.block([[tri, zero, zero], [zero, tri, zero], [zero, zero, tri]])
# alternatively: arr = np.kron(np.eye(3), tri)

tri_size = tri.shape[0]
res = arr.reshape(-1, tri_size, arr.shape[-1])[::-1, ...].reshape(arr.shape)
```

Input above:

```py
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Output:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The auxiliary array is shaped `(num_triangles, triangle_size, second_dim)` if the original array is shaped `(num_triangles * triangle_size, second_dim)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just slice the second axis in reverse: `M[:, ::-1]`

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

NB. to give an **explicit example**, this shifts from:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

to:

```
array([[ 3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  4],
       [11, 10,  9,  8],
       [15, 14, 13, 12]])
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the request. I just updated it. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
M = np.roll(M,2,axis=1) # Axis 1 for row wise
print(M)
>>> array([
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```